# How to pop out a uicollectionViewCell from the UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Hello I have a simple horizontal only uicollectionview and i want to pop out the UICollectionViewCell.

[image]

When I click a white cell i get bigger dimensions but still contained by the collection View: ->
[image]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    Fullscreen.originalHeight = (cell.frame.height)
    Fullscreen.originalWidth = (cell.frame.width)
    Fullscreen.originalX = (cell.frame.origin.x)
    Fullscreen.originalY = (cell.frame.origin.y)

    print(Fullscreen.originalX,Fullscreen.originalY,Fullscreen.originalWidth,Fullscreen.originalHeight)

    cell.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: cell)
    cell.clipsToBounds = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                   delay: 0,
                   options: .curveEaseOut,
                   animations: {

                    //fullscreen
                    cell.frame.size.height = (collectionView.superview?.frame.height)!
                    cell.frame.size.width = (collectionView.superview?.frame.width)!
                    cell.frame.origin.x = (collectionView.superview?.frame.origin.x)!
                    cell.frame.origin.y = (collectionView.superview?.frame.origin.y)!
    },completion: nil)
```

as you can see the view gets cut off by the dimensions of the Collectionview

How can i get it to pop out and have bigger dimensions than the collection view?

I could increase the contentSize.height of the collectionView but I need the white cells in horizontal line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No quite clear about what you actually want to achieve, maybe you can share some part of your code so that I can see how you are trying to implement.

Just according to your words, you can try increase the contentSize.height like you said when you pop up the cell, and put back the contentSize.height to the size before when you go back to the white one.

Comment: I just included my code. I wanted to popout to the gray area